# How to extend class from another class (Java)

Tags: java

I have two questions:

1) Is there a way to `extend` of `class A` from external file ? how?

2) I am building one class of my custom methods ( to use globally, in all my projects). Here is phseudo-code:

```
package MyFunctions;
import Twitter.profile;

public class MyFuncs{
    public String externalProfile1()  { return Twitter.profile.TwitterUrl(); }
}
```

I want Is there a way to include that file in all my projects, and avoid IDE errors, as I should be able to use any when one of the above functions in my projects...  The problem is that the `Twitter.Profile` classes are not included in all my projects, and whenever happens so - it see error in IDE("cannot find symbol method")...

how to solve the problem?

Comment: There's no "extend command" to "call". It's highly unclear what you're trying to do, and the most likely answer is that your `twitterUrl()` method belongs on `Twitter`, and perhaps you should have a `Collection<SocialAccount>` and call `getExternalProfile()` on each of them instead. Your "many functions here" smells like you're shoveling unrelated code into a kitchen-sink class.

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking myself, @chrylis is doing better. Please consider showing real code, not kind-of sort-of code.

Comment: Ok, I have simplified question. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 2:**

Just make sure all of your functions in your library are written statically:

```
public class MyFuncs{

    public static String externalProfile1(String link)     { return TwittUrl() + "/profile"; }
    public static String externalProfile2(String link)     { return YahooUrl() + "/profile"; }
}
```

And then import that class in your project files that you'll be using your library in. Then you can easily call the functions in your library. Alternatively, you can avoid importing the library in every other file and instead call the functions in a static way:

```
MyFuncs.externalProfile1("link");
```

As for `TwittUrl()`, if it doesn't require to be in a separate Class, then refactor it and put it in MyFuncs class; otherwise you can make `TwittUrl()` and `YahooUrl()` methods static in their own class.

Comment: thanks Pahlavan!... How to avoid errors, if `Twitter` class are not being used in project?